# Interacting with a document without using selection

Tags: vba, ms-word, transliteration

I have a transliteration function (from cyrillic to latin). I will use this function in a unviersal subroutine (with text of any lenght). This sub must to copy the source text, transliterate (from cyrillic to latin) and paste it below **without any formatting changes and without using selection**. The next step is reverse transliteration (again copy and paste below). There must be 3 textes in the final. I kinda know how to realize it, but i don't know what i should use **instead of selection**.

[image: an example of what it have to be in the final is in the picture]*

P.S. i tried use `For Each word In ActiveDocument.Range.Words` but it works bad with reverse transliteration (exactly that. without it, the function works perfectly in debugging)
P.P.S. sorry for mistakes in the text, i'm not a native speaker

Comment: A `selection` has the same methods/properties as a `range` object. `Range` objects don't change the selection unless you tell it to. And don't copy and paste read and write the text instead  using the text property.

Comment: @Lundt yeah i saw `range`, but i don't understand how i can set text borders of any length?

Comment: Although this is an Excel article, it should help. https://bettersolutions.com/word/paragraphs/vba-range-vs-selection.htm

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't posted any actual transliteration code, I'll leave you to add the cyrillic and latin character sets to the code below:

```
Sub Transliterate()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim p As Long, i As Long, StrLng1, StrLng2
'Insert the character codes for the cyrillic characters here
StrLng1 = Array(ChrW(&H430), ChrW(&H431), ChrW(&H432))
'Insert the corresponding latin characters here
StrLng2 = Array("a", "b", "c")
With ActiveDocument.Range
  Do While .Characters.Last.Previous = vbCr
    .Characters.Last.Previous.Delete
  Loop
  .InsertAfter vbCr
  'Duplicate Content
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Text = "^13"
    .Replacement.Text = "^l"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Text = "[!^l]@^l"
    .Replacement.Text = "^p^&"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = "^l^13"
    .Replacement.Text = "^p"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = "[!^13]@^13"
    .Replacement.Text = "^&^&^p"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
  .Characters.Last.Previous.Delete
  .Characters.First.Delete
  'Loop through duplicated paragraphs
  For p = .Paragraphs.Count - 1 To 2 Step -3
    With .Paragraphs(p).Range
      .Font.Italic = True
      'Transliterate paragraph
      With .Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchCase = True
        .Font.Bold = False
        For i = 0 To UBound(StrLng1)
          .Text = StrLng1(i)
          .Replacement.Text = StrLng2(i)
          .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        Next
      End With
      'Duplicate translated paragraph
      .Characters.Last.Next.FormattedText = .FormattedText
    End With
  Next
  .Characters.Last.Previous.Delete
  'Loop through duplicated paragraphs
  For p = .Paragraphs.Count To 3 Step -3
    With .Paragraphs(p).Range
    .Font.Underline = wdUnderlineSingle
      'Reverse Transliterate paragraph
      With .Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .Font.Bold = False
        .MatchCase = True
        For i = 0 To UBound(StrLng1)
          .Text = StrLng2(i)
          .Replacement.Text = StrLng1(i)
          .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        Next
      End With
    End With
  Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you! I have a couple of questions. I have run sub without transliteration function and it highlighted this `.Replacement.text = "^p"  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll` with an error _run-time error "5560". the find field contains an invalid search pattern_

Comment: it generally doesn't work as it should. rows are copied and pasted after each other

Comment: Depending on your regional settings, you may need to change .Text = "^13{2,}" to .Text = "^13{2;}". «it generally doesn't work as it should. rows are copied and pasted after each other» which is what your screenshot depicts... If your 'rows' are all separate paragraphs, how do you suppose we were to know that? The solution is simple - use manual line breaks instead of paragraphs breaks to separate your sets of 'rows' that are supposed to be grouped together.

Comment: it should be a universal macro, without any changes before using it. i wrote that

Comment: "If your 'rows' are all separate paragraphs, how do you suppose we were to know that?" "If your 'rows' are all separate paragraphs, how do you suppose we were to know that?" all texts consist of separate paragraphs, actually.....

Comment: «it should be a universal macro, without any changes before using it» There is no such thing as a universal macro. Every macro must be specific to the task at hand. «all texts consist of separate paragraphs, actually» That is an abysmal way to construct a document, as any proficient Word user would know. Code revised to account for your document's poor formatting.